# UWP InkToolbar ToolTip

Tags: uwp, tooltip, uwp-xaml, inkcanvas

I'm designing a InkToolbar with InkToolbarCustomToolButton, like below

```
<InkToolbar x:Name="inkToolbar1" x:FieldModifier="Public" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan ="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" InitialControls="None" TargetInkCanvas="{x:Bind inkCanvas}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <InkToolbarCustomToolButton x:Name="toggleButtonNewInk" Click="toggleButtonNewInk_Click">
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Page2" ToolTipService.ToolTip="NewInk"/>
            </InkToolbarCustomToolButton>
</InkToolbar>
```

[image]

As is shown, the button's tooltip is fixed.

[image]

Now I want to show in different languages, using Resources.resw.

For example, you can set a button's content using Resources.resw.

How can I do in the same way?

By the way, I don't want to use PointerEntered event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, you could set the `Content` of `ToolTip` just like button that you have mentioned.

```
<InkToolbarCustomToolButton x:Name="toggleButtonNewInk" Click="toggleButtonNewInk_Click" Margin="20">
    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Page2" >
        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip Content="" x:Uid="ToolTip"/>
        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
    </SymbolIcon>
</InkToolbarCustomToolButton>
```

And then set the different value for `ToolTip` in different resources file like the following:

**en-US**

```
<data name="ToolTip.Content" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>NewInk</value>
  <comment>Prompt the user this is a new ink button</comment>
</data>
```

**zh-CN**

```
<data name="ToolTip.Content" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>新画笔</value>
  <comment>提示用户这是一个新画笔按钮</comment>
</data>
```

For more, please refer to [**Put UI strings into resources**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/globalizing/put-ui-strings-into-resources).

[image]